# 301 редирект не работает со знаком вопроса

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Есть ссылка вида

```
domain.ru/news/1234/?ads=1
```

нужно переадресовать на:

```
domain.ru/ads
```

Если использовать правило

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/?ads=([0-9]+)$ /ads [R=301,L]
```

то не работает, но если заменить знак `?` на любой другой символ, все ок. 
Помогите решить проблему. Пытался экранировать

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/\?ads=([0-9]+)$ /ads [R=301,L]
```

заменять

```
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/(.)ads=([0-9]+)$ /ads [R=301,L]
```

ничего не работает.

Comment: расшифруйте "не работает" - крешиться браузер, никуда не переходит, переходит, но на левый адрес. Также попробуйте с консоли обратиться curl по данному адресу `curl -I -L domain.ru/news/1234/?ads=1` и посмотреть на вывод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ads=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/$ /ads [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Так работает, но ссылка теперь имеет вид domain.ru/ads/?ads=1

Comment: @KingStakh а если так: `RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /ads [R=301,L]`?